# checking value of a radio box from a custom field wordpress

Tags: wordpress, radio-button, custom-fields

Ive given my wordpress user a custom field in the backend which is a radio selection with three values, 1,2,3.

I want to set up conditionals so that if they select 1 then image 1 appears, if they select 2 then image 2 appears and if they select 3 then image 3 appears.

I'm currently using the following displays all thvalues of the checked buttons - but I need to use do do something like if value = 1 then do this

```
<?php 
/** Get a custom field with multiple values and return as an array */
$checkboxes_1 = get_custom_field('cft_checkboxes_1');
if( $checkboxes_1 ) {
?>
<div id="block-1" class="content-box"> 
<h2>Custom Field (multiple)</h2> 
<div class="entry"> 
    <?php print_r($checkboxes_1); ?> 
</div>
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

the custome fields are generated using the custom field template button, and the implementation of getting the results is down to [kevin leary](http://www.kevinleary.net/advanced-content-management-wordpress-custom-field-templates/)

I've put this in my functions.php to retreive the cutom fields from the database...

```
// Get Custom Field Template Values
function get_custom_field($field) {
global $post;
$custom_field_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, false);
if($custom_field_data) {
    if( count($custom_field_data) > 1 ) {
        return $custom_field_data; 
    } else {
        return $custom_field_data[0];
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: may I ask where in the WordPress Codex the 'get_custom_field' is ever documented? IMHO, this is not a WordPress code?

Comment: Wow - questions from 2011!

Nope its related to a custom fields plugin, if you read the link halfway through it talks about the plugin used and the method of custom field retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorted it thanks for a great hack [kevin leary](http://www.kevinleary.net/advanced-content-management-wordpress-custom-field-templates/) for an amazing plugin: [custom_field_templates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/)

```
<?php 
/** Get a custom field with multiple values and return as an array */
$checkboxes_1 = get_custom_field('mycustomfield');
if(($checkboxes_1 ) == 1) {
?>
// do something
<?php } else if(($checkboxes_1 ) == 2) {?>
// do something
<?php } else if(($checkboxes_1 ) == 3) { ?>
// do something
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some values to the radio buttons:

```
<input name="option" type="radio" value="1">
<input name="option" type="radio" value="2">
<input name="option" type="radio" value="3">
```

Insert those values into the database, and then query the database to see what is the value of the field for a specific user.

Comment: hi - thanks very much - I understand the principle of what needs to be done... I think I mentioned in my post that each one has a value. Its not necessarilty WHAT I need to do, its HOW to do it!! - I've updated teh question with more info